# Trouble understanding $l_0 = \{\{x_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} : \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, x_j = 0 \forall j \ge N\}$ ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Here's the question:

"Let
\begin{equation}
l_0 = \{\{x_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} : \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, x_j = 0 \forall j \ge N\}
\end{equation}
be the space of sequences with only ﬁnitely many non-zero entries. You may choose
to consider either real or complex sequences.
Show that $\overline{l_0}$ = $l_2$ in $l_2$."

I don't  think  I get what the last sentence means, "$\overline{l_0}$ = $l_2$ in $l_2$". As far as I understand, $l_2$ is the set of square-summable sequences. Since all sequences with finitely many terms are square-summable, they all belong to $l_2$. But the closure of $l_0$ seems to be simply the set of all sequences.

I would very much appreciate if someone could clarify this for me!

Comment: What you have to show is that every $l_2$-sequence is the limit of an $l_0$-sequence _in the topology of $l_2$_. The space of all sequences is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks! The word topology hasn't been used in the course I am taking, but I think I understand.

Comment: You may also read "$l_2$-norm" instead of "topology of $l_2$" if that's more familiar. I'll convert the comments to an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "$\overline{l_0} = l_2$ in $l_2$" means that:

> The set of limits (in $l_2$) of sequences with terms in $l_0$ is $l_2$.

which can in an obvious way be changed to a definition for "$\overline X = Y$ in $Z$".

In this more general context, it is understood that:

1. $X, Y \subseteq Z$;
2. We know what a "limit in $Z$ of a sequence" means.

In the case of $l_2$, this limit is probably in terms of the $l_2$-norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$, defined as:

> $$\Vert (x_j)_j\Vert_2 = \left(\sum_{j \ge 0} |x_j|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Then, we define the limit of a sequence of sequences $(x^n_j)_j$ by:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (x^n_j)_j = (x_j)_j \iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \|(x^n_j -x_j)_j\|_2 = 0$$

I hope this gives you enough information to solve the question. Hover over the grey area below for a hint.

> If $(x_j)_j \in l_2$, then: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j \ge n} |x_j|^2 = 0$. Exploit this fact by making a suitable choice of $(x^n_j)_j$.

Comment: You're welcome. If you consider your question finished, you can use the checkmark next to the answer to "accept it". This will prevent the question from being labelled "[unanswered](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered)" (due to having no accepted or upvoted answer), gain you 2 reputation, and gain me 15.